# use definitions in loop (c coding)

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, macros

I have definitons like

```
#define COLUMN1  1
#define COLUMN2  2
#define COLUMN3  a
#define COLUMN4  b
```

I want to use them in a loop

```
for (int var = 0; var < 3; ++var) {
    if(COLUMNvar) .... ; // var
}
```

Can I do like following:

```
int col[4]={COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4};
for (int var = 0; var < 3; ++var) {
    if(col(var)) .... ; // var
}
```

Comment: I have to use definiton for memory consideration :)

Comment: did you mean `#define COLUMN3  'a'`?

Comment: @SaimGokkoyun: That's not how it works. It saves you nothing. What you save in the .bss or .data segment just adds to the .text segment (the values have to be put *somewhere*). However if you use a `int const xxx[]` array it will end up in the .rodata or .text segment and it will not consume RAM either.

Comment: actually COLUMNS are referencing port definitions. They are 32 bit values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

```
#define COLUMN3  'a'
#define COLUMN4  'b'
```

and use like

```
int col[4]={COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4};
for (int var = 0; var < 4; ++var) 
{
    if(col[var])
    {
       .... ; // var //do something
    } 
}
```

you should be *syntactically* okay.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, since `define` (macros) values are replaced by the preprocessor, which is done before the compiler builds your code.

You have to do the check in a `switch` of with `if` and `else` statements.